# How do some animation with jQuery and HTML 5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

How can I do some animation like http://www.visuwords.com/ with jQuery or HTML 5?

Please give me some links or books or smth else where I can read in detail about it, or say with which functions or tags can I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to do this with the `canvas` tag.

There are several free/open-source HTML5 mind maps available:

- http://blogupstairs.com/an-opensource-html5-mind-mapping-application-mindmaps/
- etc.

And here's a tag cloud demo: http://www.goat1000.com/tagcanvas.php.

Comment: @user950067 I found the exact thing you were looking for.  The name of it had slipped my mind, but I remembered after I wrote up my answer: mind maps!

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't enough reputation to upvote yur answer, but when I have I will do it.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery won't help you that much as it's mostly good for modifying html elements (that is made to be rectangle).

You'll need to use canvas (Search for canvas and html5) or SVG. There is a good SVG library called Raphaël (http://raphaeljs.com/).

It would be possible with HTML and rotate the elements with CSS but that would be harder that to use canvas or SVG.

Comment: Thanks. But could you tell me more about canvas, is it a tag of HTNL 5 ?

Comment: It's a way of drawing geometric shapes on a canvas (yes it's a HTML5 tag) with JavaScript, I googeled up http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/ look at some examples.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't enough reputation to upvote yur answer, but when I have I will do it.